# Could not upload file - php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

I did try to upload file into the system. It does pass all necessary requirement to upload into the system. But still the file did not uploaded into it.

Here is the pinpoint location where I have spot the error occur.

As the system only read on with given **output**:

> System is busy. Please try again laterb

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        $msg = 'System is busy. Please try again laterb';
        goto ERROR;
    }
```

The code below is the full parsing of the email post on the system.

```
$email_params = array('fromEmail' => $_SESSION['user']['usr_id'], 'toEmail' => $to, 'subject' => $_POST['subject'], 'message' => $_POST['description'], 'addCC' => $cc);
$email = sendmail($email_params, 2);

if (!$email) {
    $msg = 'Failed to send email.';
     goto ERROR;
}

// Begin Upload FIle
$msg = "System is busy. Please try again later!";
$target_dir = "./images/ticket_attachments/";
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
$target_file = $target_dir . $newfilename;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if ($imageFileType != '') {
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
        if ($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            $uploadOk = 0;
            $msg = 'File is not an image';
            goto ERROR;
        }
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        $uploadOk = 0;
        $msg = 'Sorry, file already exists';
        goto ERROR;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000) {
        $uploadOk = 0;
        $msg = 'Sorry, your file is too large. Your file must be less than 500KB';
        goto ERROR;
    }

    //  Allow certain file formats
    if ($imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "txt" && $imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != "docx" && $imageFileType != "xml" && $imageFileType != "pptx" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "ppt" && $imageFileType != "xps" && $imageFileType != "pptm" && $imageFileType != "zip" && $imageFileType != "csv" && $imageFileType != "xlsx" && $imageFileType != "xls" && $imageFileType != "rar" && $imageFileType != "mp4") {
        $uploadOk = 0;
        $msg = 'Sorry, files not supported. Only jpg, jpeg, png, docx, pdf, zip, xlsx files are supported.';
        goto ERROR;
    }

    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $msg = 'System is busy. Please try again latera';
        goto ERROR;
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            $msg = 'System is busy. Please try again laterb';
            goto ERROR;
        }
    }
} else {

    $newfilename = '';
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Move_uploaded_file is returning false, this can be because it has an invalid file-name or because it cannot be moved for some reason, check logs for any warnings or extra info

Comment: I didn't even know that `goto` in php exists...

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` is showing a warning when it returns `false`. So you should enable logging and look at the console/webserver log. EDIT: It also returns false when `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` isn't a valid file, you should check that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload folder (`./images/ticket_attachments/` in your case) should be accessible by PHP.

If you run on Linux : `chmod -R 777 ./images/`

On Windows : Folder properties -> Security -> Everyone / Edit -> Grant full control to everyone

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reply. I did manage to run it on my windows localhost computer for the upload file function. But it does not work on hosting. So I guest the code runs smooth but may require credentials such as in Folder properties. Is there a way to manage it inside hosting

Comment: Typically you should have the possibility to enable the SSH console on your control panel. When it is enabled, connect to your server with a software like Putty and do the `chmod` command. A second option could be to browse your files from the control panel (you should have access to the file system inside your browser) and there maybe you can change the permissions of your upload folder.